# Configuring VNC - Grey screen

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver, vncviewer

I'm trying to login to an Ubuntu (20.04.6) PC from Windows 11 using VNC.  When I connect, I get a grey screen and can't do anything on the PC.  I'm using the GNOME desktop (v3.36.8).

I'm not sure what additional information to provide, but happy to help.  I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, so any help is greatly appreciated.  I've tried all of the settings the internet has suggested, but haven't been able to get it working.

Thanks

Comment: How do you start the VNCserver? What is the output of the VNCserver start? Add this to the question.